# ¿Cómo hacer que la redirección no sea random y siga el orden?

Tags: javascript, redirección

Tengo este código con el cual pretendo que cada vez que el mismo usuario recargue la página este lo redirija a una url diferente, el problema es que a veces redirige a la misma y lo que busco es que siga un orden, url1, url2, url3, etc.

```
var URLlist = ["url1.html","url2.html","url3.html"];

var reDelay = 0000;

setTimeout(function(){
window.location = URLlist[Math.floor(Math.random() * URLlist.length)];
}, reDelay);
```

Comment: No entiendo como es que quieras que siga un orden pero quieres que sea random...

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Almacenar en el localstorage las urls a las que ha sido redireccionado el usuario, y al momento de recargar la página tomar las URLs a las que no ha sido redireccionado.

Algo como:

```
    var URLlist = ["url1.html","url2.html","url3.html"];
    //URLs a las que el usuario ha sido redireccionado.
    var urlsRedireccionado = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("urls_redireccionado")) || [];

    var reDelay = 0000;

    setTimeout(function(){
        //La siguiente URL en el orden en que han sido agregadas en la variable URLlist
        var next = URLlist.find(u => !urlsRedireccionado.some(ur => ur == u));
        //Si faltan URL por redireccionar
        if(next) {
            urlsRedireccionado.push(next);
            window.localStorage.setItem("urls_redireccionado", JSON.stringify(urlsRedireccionado));
            window.location = next;
        } else {
            //Para que la proxima vez que recargue sea redirigido a todas las URL anteriores
            window.localStorage.removeItem("urls_redireccionado");

            //Redireccionado a todas partes
        }

    }, reDelay);
```